# Stop animation in network chart created using network D3

Tags: r, graph-visualization, networkd3

I am working on a network chart which I created using networkD3 in R. I have more than 4000 nodes in my dataset and therefore network chart looks very cluttered. Also it is taking a lot of time to build the chart completely as it works on optimizing the chart within space.

Is there any way we can stop the animation/optimization in chart once it gets created? Below is my code and sample datasets

[image]

```
EdgeList <- read.csv("C:/Users/vl9477/Downloads/EdgeList.csv", header=T, as.is=T)
NodeList <- read.csv("C:/Users/vl9477/Downloads/NodeList.csv", header=T, as.is=T)

forceNetwork(Links = EdgeList, Nodes = NodeList,
             Source = "source_id", Target = "target_id",
             Value = "Weight", NodeID = "NodeID",
             Group = "GroupID", opacity = 0.8, fontSize = 20, height = 800, width = 1500, zoom = T,
             linkDistance = 10, arrows = T, bounded = T)
```

Comment: No, that is not currently a feature of the release version of `networkD3`. Possibly you could inject Javascript to run a timer for a short period of time and then use the `simulation.stop()` function to stop the simulation.

Comment: @CJYetman Hi, thanks for the confirmation about networkD3. About adding the JavaScript, do you mean that I add this force network function inside javascript which stops working after certain seconds? Also, would I be able to achieve this if I create the network chart directly in D3JS?

Comment: It would be much more straight forward if the whole thing was written in JavaScript/d3.js

Comment: @CJYetman Thanks for the suggestion, and can we embed the entire javascript code in shiny application? If it does not affect the front end, I would be happy to create network chart in JavaScript

Comment: @CJYetman Also could you please share an example of simulation.stop with forcenetwork then it will be highly useful for me.

Comment: If you’re willing and able to write the whole thing in JavaScript, there’s no point in using Shiny at all. Google “d3 force” and probably the first link will lead you to the documentation for the d3 force module, which includes the simulation.stop function

Comment: @CJYetman Thanks. Again, I am happy to have the entire code in JS provided I am able to use that in Shiny as my dashboard and other graphs are built on shiny only

Comment: Great, glad I could help.